# fetch multi per value for jquery post

Tags: php, jquery

i have this url for post data from jquery.
how to fetch `$_POST['reciver']` multi per value

```
test.php?peygham=&onvan=&startdate=&enddate=&sal=5&nimsal=1&visible=1&pages=1&reciver%5B%5D=687&reciver%5B%5D=695&reciver%5B%5D=690
```

jquery:

```
$('#to option').prop('selected',true);
$.post("save.php",{ 
                    peygham:$('#peygham').val(), 
                    onvan:$('#onvan').val() , 
                    startdate:$('#startdateM').val() , 
                    enddate:$('#enddateM').val(),
                    sal:$('#sal').val() , 
                    nimsal:$('#nimsal').val(), 
                    visible:$('#visible').val() , 
                    pages:$('#pages').val() , 
                    reciver:$('#to').val() /* => MULTI VALUE */
                    },
    function(data){

        $('#message').show();
        $('#message').html(data.message);
        setTimeout(function() {$('#message').hide();}, 10000);
        //window.location = "http://aou.ir/manage/preForm/test.php";            
    },'json');
});
```

Comment: I don't get it, `$('#to').val()` will get the value of the first element in the matched set, and since it's an ID, there should be only one element in the matched set. How exactly are you getting multiple values ??

Answer (score 0):

You can get it as array

```
foreach($_POST['reciver'] as $value){
  echo $value;
}
```